# Select query with and/or in the from/join clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have SQL Select query like so:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

is there a way to use AND/OR in the JOIN clause? something like this:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON (
Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
 AND
Orders.CustomerName = Customers.CustomerName
)
```

I am not even sure if that makes sense - but if this is possible, if someone knows the name of this type of query, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple join condition.

Below queries are valid

```
Select a.a1, b.b1 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.a1=b.a1 and a.b1=b.b1;
```

You can even have filters, functions as well.

```
Select a.a1, b.b1 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.a1=b.a1 and a.b1=b.b1 and b.c1='someValue';

Select a.a1, b.b1 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.a1=b.a1 and a.b1=b.b1 and <functions>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON 
Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID 
AND Orders.CustomerName = Customers.CustomerName
```

Yes it is possible to join on multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put any boolean expression in the `on` clause, even a reference to a subquery.  So this is valid:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderDate
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN
     Customers c
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND
        o.CustomerName = c.CustomerName;
```

That said, you have a problem with your data model.  You should not be storing the customer name twice -- in both the `Orders` table and the `Customers` table.  It should be in the `Customers` table.  And, you can look it up using `CustomerId`.

So, I would recommend fixing your data model so you don't need to use two keys for this `JOIN`.